# One Promise from multiple files

Tags: javascript, html

The example below shows a snippet of my application. The assumption is: some functions are executed after the document is loaded, others only after the POST response. On this momet, callbacks are placed in the array and executed after the request is completed. It all works as expected. I would like to change these callbacks to one Promise which would be fired just like now "Update.endRequest()"; I wonder if it is possible? Any suggestions are welcome. Or an idea if it can be done better.

update.js

```
class UpdateClass {
    constructor() {
        this.callbacks = [];
    }

    success(callback) {
        this.callbacks.push(callback);
    }

    endRequest() {
        this.callbacks.forEach(callback => callback());
    }
}

const Update = new UpdateClass();
export default Update;
```

file1.js

```
import Update from './update';

export default class File1Class {
    constructor () {
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        Update.success(this.update);

        exampleFunction();
    }

    update() {
        exampleFunctionAfterUpdate();
    }
}

function exampleFunction() {
    console.log('On document load 1');
}

function exampleFunctionAfterUpdate() {
    console.log('After Update 1');
}
```

file2.js

```
import Update from './update';

export default class File2Class {
    constructor () {
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        Update.success(this.update);

        anotherExampleFunction();
    }

    update() {
        anotherExampleFunctionAfterUpdate();
    }
}

function anotherExampleFunction() {
    console.log('On document load 2');
}

function anotherExampleFunctionAfterUpdate() {
    console.log('After Update 2');
}
```

app.js

```
import Update from './update';
import File1Class from './file1';
import File2Class from './file2';

class AppClass {
    constructor () {
        this.init();
    }
    
    init() {
        new File1Class();
        new File2Class();
        
        triggerfunction();
    }
}

function triggerfunction() {
    const button = document.getElementById('trigger');
    
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        xhr.open('POST', 'someUrl', true);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                Update.endRequest();
            }
        };
        xhr.send(someJsonData);
    });
}

window.app = new AppClass();
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with promises?

Comment: I would like to define a global variable which will be Promise as now function "success" in update class with the possibility of binding to it from different places but get resolve only after the request is completed.

Comment: But you are doing multiple requests, are you not? Every time the click handler in `triggerFunction` is called? So it should not be a global promise.

Comment: TriggerFunction is just an example that I need to call multiple functions from different places at the end of the request. In fact, it may be an action of adding a product to the cart that requires updating a few elements on the page and calling specific functions based on the action performed. This invoked action is passed to the update class and on to each callback. Based on this, I can decide which methods will be called after the update.

Comment: You cannot use a promise for that. A promise only resolves once. You might be adding products to the cart multiple times. Your `Update` object with a list of callbacks is well-equipped to handle that. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe I wanted to use the Promise here, although there was no need and, as you write, it is not suitable for it. The opinion from the outside that the current solution is OK will allow me to move on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```js
const promiseObj = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  exampleFunctionAfterUpdate();
  anotherExampleFunctionAfterUpdate();
  resolve(true);
});

function triggerfunction() {
    const button = document.getElementById('trigger');
    
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        xhr.open('POST', 'someUrl', true);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                // Update.endRequest();
                promiseObj.then(()=> console.log('Functions executed'));
            }
        };
        xhr.send(someJsonData);
    });
}
```

Comment: This solution would work if I had everything in one file. For clarity and ease of navigation, I have applications splited into smaller modules.

Comment: You can export the required functions from other modules and import the function in the main file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But in fact, there are hundreds of functions in dozens of files. Exporting and loading them in one place will be impossible. Most routes in an application have their own .js file created by webpack and without common stuff loaded is only what is necessary on specyfic url.